# Does the second half of a というのは sentence need to end with a noun or い-adjective?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I was reading a forum post and saw a comment replying to someone who said they chose not to curse/chew out people online. Their response was saying that it's not a physically dangerous thing to do, but then added:

ただ、確かにそういう暴力性を心の中では持ち合わせている**というのは**、恐怖の対象には**なり得る**な。
"But the fact that you have that kind of violent nature in your mind can be a source of fear" [presumably for others].

I previously thought that the Y statement after というのは had to either end in either a noun or an い-adjective, especially if the X statement before というのは is a verb.

Here the X statement ends with 持ち合わせている, and the Y statement ends with なり得る.

I remember being corrected for saying:

日本語ができるようになるというのは時間がかかるなあ

to instead → 日本語ができるようになるというのは時間がかかる**こと**だなあ.

"Becoming able to speak Japanese takes time"

What is different here about these というのは sentences? Why can you end with a verb in the first one but not the second?

Comment: It is rather that 日本語ができるようになるという事 and 時間がかかる do not come together, just like *That one becomes fluent in Japanese takes time* does not work in English.